# Flutter Scaffold with one or more TextFormFields and a bottom aligned button: "Each child must be laid out exactly once."

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So this is mostly behaving as expected layout-wise and without any "render overflow" errors, but I am getting these Scaffold exceptions:

1. `'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5022 pos 16: 'child is! ParentDataElement<ParentData>': is not true.`
2. `Each child must be laid out exactly once.`
3. `Updated layout information required for RenderErrorBox#ade8d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT to calculate semantics. 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 2647 pos 12: '!_needsLayout'`

My Scaffold (somewhat simplified):

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    child: MainAppBar(
      title: 'Registration',
   ),
   preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        FirstRegistrationScreenForm(
          formKey: _formKey,
          employerController: _employerController,
          employmentStatusController: _employmentStatusController,
          zipcodeController: _zipcodeController,
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .85,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 48.0,
            buttonColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text(
                'NEXT',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: "NimbusSanL-Bol",
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

And the `FirstRegistrationScreenForm` widget (The parent-most widget being returned and one form-field placeholder):

```
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 40, 40, 0),
    child: Form(
      key: widget.formKey,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
            child: Text(
              'Who is your most recent employer?',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontFamily: "NimbusSanL-Bol",
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            ),
          ),
          /// This is where the TextFormField goes
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

So the main Stack tree from Scaffold to TextFormField is `Scaffold->Column->Expanded->Expanded->Container->Form->ListView`. If I remove the parent-most `Expanded` widget the keyboard flashes upward for a moment and then disappears without any exception. Any thoughts on a path forward to cleanly resolve this? This is the design I am attempting to implement:
[image]

Comment: why 2 expanded?

Comment: Honestly at this point just experimentation. I need the "NEXT" button to be on the bottom and yet resize for the keyboard. The first expanded keeps the button on the bottom. I was then running into an issue where the keyboard momentarily opens and then immediately disappears, so I added another Expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove one of the expanded and delete all this :

```
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .85,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 48.0,
            buttonColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text(
                'NEXT',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: "NimbusSanL-Bol",
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

and wrap your button inside a column to have something like this :

```
Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(children: [
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
              ],),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'NEXT',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: "NimbusSanL-Bol",
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks! That's super helpful, though I think the issue I am running into with the keyboard appearing then disappearing is that I am passing a key to a form that surrounds the ListView, which seems to be forcing another build when focusing an input. So, this stack: 
```
Expanded(
              child: ListView(children: [
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
              ],),
            ),
```
looks more like : `Expanded->Container->Form->ListView->children`.

Comment: If you even just wrap the above ListView from your example in a Form with a `GlobalKey<FormState>()`, it causes the keyboard to grow appear/disappear, effectively disabling it. Not sure how I can achieve this layout, with validation on all fields...

Comment: Alright never mind. I'm a fool and was declaring keys/controllers in the build method. Thanks for the help with the layout!